# i can't retrieve all data of a specific row with angular

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm building a project with angular and php. I have a customer table and I can retrieve all table data, and when I enter a specific customer it shows me only the customer_id and not the rest of customer details. can someone help please?

**customerCardDetailsCtrl.js** - controller for the page that show all information of a specific customer:

```
"use strict";
angular.module('dataSystem').controller('customerCardDetailsCtrl', function($scope, $http ,$routeParams, $location) {

  var customer_id = $routeParams.customer_id;
  $scope.customer_id = customer_id;


  $http.get('http://localhost:8081/hamatkin/api/get-allCustomers.php/'+ customer_id).success(function(data){
    $scope.customerDetail = data;
  });
});
```

**customerCardDetails.html** - html page that show only `customer_id`

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="customer">
    <h1>כרטיס לקוח</h1>
    <a href="/hamatkin/index.html#/customerCards">חזור לרשימת כרטיסי הלקוחות</a>
    <h1 ng-bind="customerDetail.customer_id"></h1> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js** -

```
  .when('/customerCardDetails/:customer_id', {
                controller: "customerCardDetailsCtrl",
                templateUrl: '../hamatkin/Views/customerCardDetails.html',
                screenTitle: "",
                costumerHidden: false,
                reportsHidden: true,
                stockHidden: true,
                isIncome_expensesHidden: true,
                isNavTabHidden: false,
                isFooterHidden: false,
                ordersHidden: true
```

Answer (score 0):

The design is wrong.

In controller-  You are using route parameters though they are not on the route url.
Your api returns data in customerDetail , this object should be ideally having details of customer you are looking for. So use that in html bindings.

In html - the outer most div is using ng-model , which is wrong as its 2 way binding use ng-bind.

Ng-model has an undefined scope object.

Many more pblms in the code . Review it

Comment: Now it looks fine technically.     Now whats the pblm u r getting in the application?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you're doing with `ng-models="customers"` as that variable isn't defined anywhere - you can remove that bit.

The entire block starting from `var kind_Of_Customer` and ending with `$scope.activePath = null;` can be removed.

You want the data returned from the GET request, so handle it in the GET request's callback. Or you can just replace

`<h1>{{customer_id}}</h1>`

with

`<h1>{{customerDetail.customer_id}}</h1>`.

Or, to [avoid `{{}}` showing up](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) while the request is loading:

`<h1 ng-bind="customerDetail.customer_id"></h1>`

(I'd also suggest putting requests like these in a service to separate the two)

Comment: i did what u said but its still doesn't work. and the console not showing any errors. what could be the problem?

Comment: how to put those requests in the service?

Comment: Actually, if you put `console.log($scope.customerDetail)` right under `$scope.customerDetail = data;` do you see the expected results? Would like to make sure that nothing else is the issue.  edit: regarding separation of requests, look at something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854296/angularjs-scope-doesnt-update-after-a-get-request-on-a-factory

Comment: Wait a second, is the code you edited all the code you have? If you don't have something like `<span ng-bind="customerDetail.full_name"></span>`, for whatever field of `customerDetail` you have, of course you don't have anything else showing

Comment: i did what you said - the console showing me a array of all data but the html page isn't shoing anything, what could be the problem?

Comment: so including <span ng-bind="customerDetail.full_name"></span> didn't do anything? And the html page doesn't show anything? Not even the customer_id?