# How do I get my request data into my $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, asynchronous, passport.js

I m currently really stuck on this topic.

I want to append the response data that I am retrieving from Express to my angular $scope and then redirect the user to their profile page.

My Controller Function looks like this:

```
$scope.login = function($event){
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/login',
      data: {
          email: $scope.email,
          password: $scope.password
      }
  }).success(function(data){
      console.log(data.events)
      $scope.events = data.events
      $location.path('/profile');
  }).error(function(err){
      console.log(err)
  })
```

Once I try to log in I get the logged data and then I'm redirected as desired. But my ng-repeat directive doesn't update.

JSON Output from my logged data:

```
[{
"type":"fussball",
"distance":"1",
"date":"Morgen",
"time":"10:30",
"maxAttendees":10,
"attendees:[
1345455466,
323232324,
454554534343,
898493839489,
892839283928,
283293283983]}
```

ng-repeat section:

```
<div ng-class="{'first': $first}" class="event-item"ng-repeat="event in events">
    <div class="event-type {{event.type}}"></div>
    <div class="event-seperator"></div>
    <div class="event-body">
        <div class="event-body-inner">
            <span class="date"></span>
            <p class="main">{{event.date}}</p>
            <p class="sub">{{event.time}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="event-body-inner">
            <span class="attendees"></span>
            <p class="main">{{event.attendees.length}}{{checkAttendees($index)}}</p>
            <p class="sub">TEILNEHMER</p>
        </div>
        <div class="event-body-inner">
            <span class="distance"></span>
            <p class="main">{{event.distance}}</p>
            <p class="sub">KM</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-seperator"></div>
    <div ng-click="selecEvent($event)" class="eventGo hvr-bounce-to-left">
        <p>GO</p>
    </div>
    <div class="event-clicked">
        <p>+  ZU <a href="/#/events">DEINEN EVENTS</a> HINZUGEFÜGT</p>
    </div>
```

I'm actually not so familiar with asynch/synch programming so I hope someone can give me a hint ;) .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your json and the ng-repeat part

Comment: I already changed data.events to data only but still nothing changes on $location change! I tried to paste that ng-repeat to my login template and removed the redirect and there all items showed up.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a factory for this. I was about to write it but I found another question in another post.

Please up-vote the original poster if you like the comment.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21855302/1549291

EDIT: Added plunker link for the implementation:
https://plnkr.co/edit/EimStRS1yMPbiU6PWKJN

```
(function () {
//factory

angular.module('app')
.factory('appFactory', ['$http', function ($http){

  this.getlist = function(){            
        return $http.get('data.json')
            .then(function(response) {
              return response.data;
            });            
    };
    return this;
}]);

}());

angular.module('app').controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$log','$location', 'appFactory',
//controller   
    function($scope, $http, $log, $location, appFactory) {

    // Chapters  json data
    appFactory.getlist()
    .then(function(data) {
        $scope.events = data;
    });

}]);
```

Comment: Do you think I can use a factory function without sending another get request and just pass the existing response?

Comment: There is only one instance of GET being executed as per that example.You can use this factory any time you need to make the call.

Comment: I tried it with a factory and with a service but both don't work. But thanks for trying ;)

Comment: I implemented your code in the plunker using JSON as the input. Check it out. It is stripped down but works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell angular that there is an async update on the event list

```
  }).success(function(data){
  console.log(data.events)
  $scope.events = data.events
  $scope.$apply(); // <----- try to add this line
  $location.path('/profile');
```

Maybe you would like to read:

[When to use $scope.$apply()](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply())

and to watch:

[Difference between $apply and $digest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LgDgazlr_Kw)

Comment: I already tried this nur I'm getting the error that a digest cycle is running!